# heroku page not displaying most recent migrations

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Hey I have run it to this issue for a little while now and while I have found several close answers none have solved my problem. 
My problem: when I create migrations for my heroku hosted django app I the run but then are never reflected on the live page. Here is the message I recieved and the command I ran

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Aaron\workcrew> heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running `python manage.py migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.7754
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, auth, workCrew, contenttypes, admin
Running migrations: 

Applying workCrew.0003_auto_20150606_1849... OK
```

After seeing this message there is no response on my django admin page even though I received the success message. Any help would be appreciated, and yes I did makemigrations locally and push them to heroku so that I could run them there as per this [advice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462558/cannot-migrate-pending-migrations)

Comment: What are you expecting to see on your admin page?

Comment: I am have a class Job model and I have added a display name field. When I make the migrations on my local db it adds the new field in the add/edit existing entry page. However, on the heroku site there is no change.